# Matching points to raster in different projections

Tags: raster, r-sp, rgdal

I'm mapping occurrence data for a species of interest to rasters of climate data from DAYMET, but I'm having trouble matching the points to the rasters.

Basically, I have a raster of daymet climate data (tmin) which has no projection when downloaded but is in Lambert conformal conic (https://daac.ornl.gov/DAYMET/guides/Daymet_mosaics.html), so I set the CRS:

```
#import daymet raster
tmin=raster("Tmin.tif")

#set projection for daymet data -> Lambert conformal
proj4string(tmin)<-CRS("+proj=lcc +lon_0=-100 +lat_0=42.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60")
```

And then I import the occurrence data which is in WGS84 lat/long(x,y), project, and transform to match tmin:

```
#import occurrences -> sp points 
species<- read.csv("species_sites.csv", header=T)
coordinates(species)=~X+Y

#project occurences
projection(species) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 ")
species <- spTransform(species, crs(tmin)) #transform to match daymet raster
```

The problem is they don't match when you plot together, and if you look at the extents they are off by a couple orders of magnitude:

```
> species
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 219 
extent      : 658883.2, 687373.3, 398524.3, 441106.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       : Site, Species, Season 
min values  :    1,      0,      - 
max values  :  219,      1,   2014 

> tmin
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 126, 138, 17388  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 591.25, 729.25, 355.5, 481.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lon_0=-100 +lat_0=42.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60  
names       : Tmin 
values      : -9.410258, -7.011579  (min, max)
```

So I matched extents:

```
species@bbox<-as.matrix(extent(tmin))
```

but the points still don't match the raster. Not sure what else to do. Any suggestions or people with more detailed knowledge of the daymet data that might know whats going on?

Comment: I think the problem is arising because your raster layer's spatial unit is Km while point data has meters units.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rar, figured that out last night...doh.

just needed to change CRS to:

```
CRS("+proj=lcc +lon_0=-100 +lat_0=42.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +datum=WGS84 +units=km")
```